# How to write tests for super in custom error class (Typescript)

Tags: typescript, error-handling, jestjs, ts-jest

I am writing test for custom error class and want to cover all lines, but I am not sure how to test super call, also I want to return the barcode provided to object when creation.

```
export class BarcodeDecoderError extends Error {
  constructor(
    message: string,
    public readonly barcode: string,
    public readonly errorType: ErrorType
  ) {
    super(message);
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! If I understand you correctly, all you would need to do is write a test calling the constructor of `BarcodeDecoderError` and checking if the `message` property is set correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing a test should be pretty straightforward. Coverage means **"Does this line get executed while running my tests"**. So calling the constructor of `BarcodeDecoderError` should do the trick. Of course you'll probably also want to test, if the super call has the desired effect:

```js
it('instantiates BarcodeDecoderError with all properties', () => {
    const error = new BarcodeDecoderError('message', 'barcode', ErrorType.Something);
    expect(error.message),toBe('message'); // Test if super call worked
    expect(error.barcode).toBe('barcode');
    expect(error.errorType).toBe(ErrorType.Something);
})
```

*(possibly adjust to your test framework)*

---

Having full coverage usually only becomes a problem when **branches** are involved (`if`, `switch/case`, conditional `loops`), or if you are building a library exposing functions not used in your code.

In your specific example, it might be enough to test the `BarcodeDecoderError` in an actual example and have coverage as a byproduct:

```js
it('throws BarcodeDecoderError with all properties', () => {
    // Decode something where you would expect an error
    const decoder = new BarcodeDecoder();
    expect(decoder.decode()).toThrow(expect.objectContaining({
        message: 'message',
        barcode: 'barcode',
        errorType: ErrorType.Something
    }))
})
```